# Symfony custom route works with frontend_dev.php but not with index.php

Tags: routes, symfony1, http-status-code-404

Am I missing something or should my custom route work with the index.php (or nothing) instead of frontend_dev.php? I'm getting a 500 error when I go to the model, and a 404 for the show page. My route is:

```
project_show:
  url:     /project/:slug
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: Project, type: object }
  param:   { module: project, action: show }
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Darren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to clear the cache: `./symfony cc`. If that won't help just check what error is thrown (you can find an error message in your logs).

Comment: It was the cache, how annoying! Disabled for now! Thanks!